# SQL Server sys.objects and Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

SQL Server 2005 and later stores metadata in the sys tables (sys.objects, sys.columns etc.)

Using Entity Framework 4 in Visual Studio 2010 is it practical to generate a model on these sys tables as a way of working with the metadata? My intent is to use it read-only.

Comment: Actuallly, those elements in the `sys.` schema are catalog **views** - not tables. The actual underlying tables are internal to SQL Server and cannot be accessed. And from the looks of it, you cannot import those system views into an EF model - at least not directly....

Comment: @marc_s, I think you could probably map them by hand. The designer probably removes them from the list of available tables as a convenience to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Probably easier to use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views for this.  My guess would be that they are ignored by the EF Framework.  However, you could wrap them in your own views and access them that way.

Comment: I've had good success creating classes for views in EF code first. Wrapping the sys. catalogs in custom views is a good solution for me.